# What can you get from each one of the Isle Aphun's treasure hunting options in Poké Pelago?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

There is four different kinds of treasure hunting on Isle Aphun in Poké Pelago:

- Path for Odd-Shard Hunting!
- Path for Brilliant-Stone Hunting!
- Path for Rare-Treasure Hunting!
- Path for Interesting-Item Hunting!

I have some ideas on what kind of items can be obtained for each one of those, but I am not sure if you can for instance use one of those treasure hunting options to find items like the [Electrizer](http://pokemon.wikia.com/wiki/Electirizer) or such. What are the different items you can obtain from the different treasure hunting options on Isle Aphun?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The three first options are indeed quite different from each other, as the items that your Pokémon will find depending on the selected option serve really different purposes. The last option is a combination of the three first ones. Do note that none of these options will bring you items which are needed to evolve some Pokémon under special conditions while holding it, like the [Electrizer](http://pokemon.wikia.com/wiki/Electirizer) or the [Razor Fang](http://pokemon.wikia.com/wiki/Razor_Fang).

Each item does not have the same chance to be found in each category. Some are way more rare than the others.

---

[image: Path for Odd-Shard Hunting!]

## Path for Odd-Shard Hunting!

This option will mainly bring you colored shards, that you can exchange to the Old Man in Festival Plaza for Bottle Caps.

- [Blue Shard](http://www.serebii.net/itemdex/blueshard.shtml) (Very Common)
- [Green Shard](http://www.serebii.net/itemdex/greenshard.shtml) (Very Common)
- [Red Shard](http://www.serebii.net/itemdex/redshard.shtml) (Very Common)
- [Yellow Shard](http://www.serebii.net/itemdex/yellowshard.shtml) (Very Common)
- [Hard Stone](http://www.serebii.net/itemdex/hardstone.shtml) (Common)
- [Revive](http://www.serebii.net/itemdex/revive.shtml) (Common)
- [Star Piece](http://www.serebii.net/itemdex/starpiece.shtml) (Common)

---

[image: Path for Brilliant-Stone Hunting]

## Path for Brilliant-Stone Hunting!

This option will mainly bring you evolving stones.

- [Everstone](http://www.serebii.net/itemdex/everstone.shtml) (Very Common)
- [Hard Stone](http://www.serebii.net/itemdex/hardstone.shtml) (Very Common)
- [Float Stone](http://www.serebii.net/itemdex/floatstone.shtml) (Very Common)
- [Fire Stone](http://www.serebii.net/itemdex/firestone.shtml) (Common)
- [Ice Stone](http://www.serebii.net/itemdex/icestone.shtml) (Common)
- [Leaf Stone](http://www.serebii.net/itemdex/leafstone.shtml) (Common)
- [Moon Stone](http://www.serebii.net/itemdex/moonstone.shtml) (Common)
- [Oval Stone](http://www.serebii.net/itemdex/ovalstone.shtml) (Common)
- [Sun Stone](http://www.serebii.net/itemdex/sunstone.shtml) (Common)
- [Thunder Stone](http://www.serebii.net/itemdex/thunderstone.shtml) (Common)
- [Water Stone](http://www.serebii.net/itemdex/waterstone.shtml) (Common)
- [Dawn Stone](http://www.serebii.net/itemdex/dawnstone.shtml) (Rare)
- [Dusk Stone](http://www.serebii.net/itemdex/duskstone.shtml) (Rare)
- [Light Clay](http://www.serebii.net/itemdex/lightclay.shtml) (Rare)
- [Shiny Stone](http://www.serebii.net/itemdex/shinystone.shtml) (Rare)

---

[image: Path for Rare-Treasure Hunting]

## Path for Rare-Treasure Hunting!

This option will mainly bring you high value items that you will be able to sell to any store.

- [Hard Stone](http://www.serebii.net/itemdex/hardstone.shtml) (Very Common)
- [Pearl](http://www.serebii.net/itemdex/pearl.shtml) (Very Common)
- [Big Pearl](http://www.serebii.net/itemdex/bigpearl.shtml) (Common)
- [Nugget](http://www.serebii.net/itemdex/nugget.shtml) (Common)
- [Pearl String](http://www.serebii.net/itemdex/pearlstring.shtml) (Common)
- [Rare Bone](http://www.serebii.net/itemdex/rarebone.shtml) (Common)
- [Big Nugget](http://www.serebii.net/itemdex/bignugget.shtml) (Rare)
- [Comet Shard](http://www.serebii.net/itemdex/cometshard.shtml) (Rare)
- [Gold Bottle Cap](http://www.serebii.net/itemdex/goldbottlecap.shtml) (Very Rare)

---

[image: Path for Interesting-Item Hunting]

## Path for Interesting-Item Hunting!

This option is giving you the opportunity to select all the options at the same time. If you go for this one, you will get a combination of any of the items that you can get with the three other options.

(Sources: [Serebii](http://www.serebii.net/sunmoon/pokepelago.shtml), [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9_Pelago)).